# Decompose a vector in rotational components

Tags: math, linear-algebra

Given a random normalized 3D vector, how can I parameterize it with two consecutive rotations of any unit vector around two axes in the cartesian coordinate system?

Comment: Well, first you can rotate your unit vector to match in XY plane (heading), then rotate it around the now-shared vectors plane (pitch).

Comment: The rotations should be limited to the cartesion axes though... Your suggestion implies a rotation around an arbitrary axis.

Comment: I was talking about Cartesian axes.

Comment: Well, lets say the vector (1,1,0) matches another vector (1,1,1) in the XY plane (not unit vectors here for simplicity). How are you going to match both vectors with one single rotation around one of the cartesian axes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a starting unit vector u and your random unit vector v.

Vector u defines a unique circle Cx of all unit vectors who have the same x-coordinate as u, and hence can be reached from u by a rotation around the x-axis.

Vector v defines a unique circle Cz of all unit vectors who have the same z-coordinate as v, and hence can reach v by a rotation around the z-axis.

Circles Cx and Cz intersect at two unit vectors. Call w one of these two vectors. Vector w has the same x-coordinate as u and the same z-coordinate as v; you can find its y-coordinate easily because it's a unit vector: wy^2 = 1 - wx^2 - wz^2.

You can calculate the angles from u to w and from w to v using trigonometry:

- cos(angle_x(u,w)) = (uy wy + uz wz) / (1 - ux^2)
- cos(angle_z(w,v)) = (wx vx + wy vy) / (1 - vz^2)

These trigonometric expressions are found by considering the "dot-product of u and w in the yz-plane" and the "dot-product of w and v in the xy-plane" and noting that the radius of Cx is cos(arcsin(ux))=1-ux^2.

Comment: Thanks, the hint with the unique circles which match at two positions was very helpful. Since rotations are generally not commutative, I had some trouble to find a reasonable approach.